# How to send complex object using Jersey client to a jax-rc server?

Tags: rest, jersey, cxf, jax-rs, jersey-client

I have designed a REST client and server. Server uses spring and CXF and some services that @Procoduces and @Consumes some objects. This is prototype of the services :

```
@GET
@Produces("application/xml")
@Path("/Order/Id/{orderId}")
public Order getOrder(@PathParam("orderId") String officeId);

@GET
@Produces("application/xml")
@Path("/Order/All")
public OrderList getAllOrders();

@POST
@Consumes("application/xml")
@Path("/Order/")
public String sendOrder(Order order);
```

GET request with `/Order/All` path, responses correctly but when I POST to `/Order/` path using Jersey client don't work. this is client code :

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource("server address/Order/");
ClientResponse response = webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        .post(ClientResponse.class, `an order object`);
```

And I got this exception on server:

```
2014-01-26 12:22:33 WARN  JAXRSUtils:499 - No operation matching request path "/services/Order/Hey" is found, Relative Path: /Order/, HTTP Method: POST, ContentType: application/xml, Accept: application/xml,. Please enable FINE/TRACE log level for more details.
2014-01-26 12:22:33 WARN  WebApplicationExceptionMapper:73 - javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.findTargetMethod(JAXRSUtils.java:503)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:218)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:239)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:167)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:286)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:206)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not targeting `POST` request to `/services/Order/` but to `/services/Order/Hey` (it's in the exception). This resource doesn't exist in your application. Check whether the client is using correct URI or whether your application doesn't contain any filter capable of changing the request URI.

Answer (score 0):

Your REST pattern doesn't follow the most common convention. This causes confusion! In particular, it is normal to model the collection of orders as a single resource, e.g., `/Orders`, and have the individual orders as sub-resources, `/Orders/{id}`. To get this, you'd annotate your methods like this:

```java
@GET
@Produces("application/xml")
@Path("/Order/{orderId}")
public Order getOrder(@PathParam("orderId") String orderId);

@GET
@Produces("application/xml")
@Path("/Order")
public OrderList getAllOrders();

@POST
@Consumes("application/xml")
@Produces("text/plain")
@Path("/Order")
public String sendOrder(Order order);
```

(You *probably* want to return a `Response` from the POST handler there, and maybe pass in a `@Context UriInfo ui` parameter too; that will allow you to send a redirect to the created order resource. But that's not so critical.)

Once you've done that, your GET request to `/services/Order/Hey` becomes meaningful, resulting in the implementation's `getOrder` method being called with `orderId` set to "`Hey`".